# NullPointerException When back from background

Tags: android, garbage-collection, nullpointerexception, android-activity

My app has about 3-depth activity hierachy.

And many activity or fragment use UserVo in MainApplication.

So I get UserVo in activity or fragment.

```
UserVo user;

onCreate() {
    user = MainApplicatoin.getSingleton().getUser();
    // ...
}
// ...
onClick(View v) {
    textView.setText(user.getData().name);
}
```

But Sometimes It occurs NullPointerException when back into my app from background.

I think It occurs by GC.

How to prevent user == null, or restart my app when user == null?

==

MainApplication.java (I set this to application in manifest)

```
private static MainApplication sigleton;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    singleton = this;
    }

MainApplication getSington() {
    return singelton;}
```

Comment: can you post your singleton class?

Comment: you can use to store data in `SharedPreferance` instead of Vo class if it is not long.

Comment: @SilentKiller I can save But I want to restart not restore...

Comment: @BirajZalavadia onCreate is not problem, when return back and use user, It occurs exception like code in onClick() method

Comment: Why are you accessing the `User's` data from MainApplication.java and not keeping it in a persistent state ?

Comment: @ChangUZ have you initilized TextView..??? or can you show your logcat.?

Comment: @SilentKiller TextView is just sample. I did check user is null

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani I think application class does not lose data.

Comment: @ChangUZ Well i am not sure about that, but if you are not receiving data properly and sometimes receiving it as null, then it means that there is a problem with your flow. So i guess, Data Persistence is a better solution to apply here instead of relying onto a Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line is causing the problem when you press the back button:

```
user = MainApplicatoin.getSingleton().getUser();
```

user becomes null in the current activity (Lets say Activity A) when you move to the next activity (Lets say Activity B). So when you press back you get the nullpoint exception.

Possible solution is:

When you are trying to move to Activity B from A (may be on a button press), pass the value of 'user' to the next activity which is activity B. Then capture it there.

Override the backPress in Activity B:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
            //here pass the captured user value back to Activity A.....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about when your app come to background, the system may recycle it when low memery.

So you can make UserVo become a Parcelable class, save it in activity's onSaveInstanceState function, and read it in onRestoreInstanceState function, code as follows.

```
void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   ...
   outState.putParcelable("user", user);
   ...
}

void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   user = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("user");
   ...
}
```